# Swift: Access files in Documents Dictionary from webpage stored in Main Bundle

Tags: html, ios, swift, bundle

I'm loading an HTML webpage from the main bundle in my Swift iOS app, which is working perfectly well. However, I'd like to reference a file stored in the documents dictionary from the HTML webpage. I can't quite figure how to cross reference between the Documents and Main Bundle locations. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you instead of open url directly to webview you need to download contain of url and convert it to string which gave you html string.

than replace a path with your local path to that html string.

Open modified html string to webview.

hope this will help you.

Comment: So by this do you mean copying the HTML to the documents directory too?

Comment: no you don't need to copy html. You have to hold it as a string.

Comment: I've attempted that but I'm still experiencing the same issue - how should I be referencing the Documents Directory from the HTML?

Comment: is it possible for you to copy html string in question and indicate what you need to replace?

Comment: Ah okay wait, yes, I understand now. I've managed to now load some assets, but there's a mixture of where I need to source the files from. I'm afraid I can't post it though. There's a couple of XMLs which need to be linked from the HTML file, which I don't really want to store in document directory, but there will be some downloaded images in the document directory, which also need to be referenced. That's where my main issue lies now...